# how to find objects which are in a list, but not in another list, comparing by property. in python2

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists of objects in python2. They are of different types but have a common property ('name'). I control one list (my_list) and the other is sent to me (src_list).

I want to find *new* objects in src_list, that aren't in my_list, by comparing their 'name' property.

The pseudo code (and how I'd do this in C) is below, but I'm after a python way of doing it, probably list comprehensions and stuff but I couldn't figure it out.

```
new_list = []
for srco in src_list: # iterate everything in src list
    found = False
    for myo in my_list: # iterate everything in my list
        if(srco.name.lower() == myo.name.lower()): # compare names, break if true
            found = True
            break
    if not found: # add to new list if wasn't found
        new_list.append(srco)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a set for fast lookups.

```
my_list_names = {obj.name.lower() for obj in my_list}
new_list = [obj for obj in src_list if obj.name.lower() not in my_list_names]
```

Also, if you want to learn to be more pythonic, don't do the `found` pattern. Do this:

```
for myo in my_list:
    if(srco.name.lower() == myo.name.lower()):
        break
else:  # executes if there was no break
    new_list.append(srco)
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to first generate set of names to exclude from `my_list` and then iterate over `src_list` keeping the items that can't be found from set:

```
exclude = {x.name.lower() for x in my_list}
new_list = [x for x in src_list if x.name.lower() not in exclude]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use sets to do that.
Create a set with containing the my_list names, another set containing src_list and simply substract the two :

```
diff_set = src_list_set - my_list_set
```

And you can then go fetch the objects whose names appear in diff_set

```
my_list_set = {obj.name.lower() for obj in my_list}
src_list_set = {obj.name.lower() for obj in src_list}
diff_set = src_list_set - my_list_set
new_list = [obj for obj in src_list if obj.name.lower() in diff_set]
```

(the solution may not be specially short but by replacing the minus by an other operation you can find [on the official doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), it fits at a minimal cost many other situations)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, list comprehension comes to mind like you already said. Then, the `map` builtin can be used to create an iterator for the names from one of the lists.

```
result = [obj for obj in srco if obj.name.lower() not in set(map(lambda x: x.name.lower(), myo))]
```